# magento create order after successful payment from ccavenue

Tags: magento, ccavenue

I have implemented cc-avenue payment gateway in my magento store.

right now when i select ccavenue payment method while checkout it redirects to ccavenue but in backend magento create a order.

i want to create a order after successfull payment of ccavenue.

can anyone help me for this.

Comment: In magento, by default order will be created with the status processing. After completing the payment it will mark it as success or failed based on the status.

Comment: I dont think its a good option for you. because you will lose information of customers who tried to order and finally they didt ordered.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I am struggling for same for EuropaBank MPI payment method, you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In magento you have to create a order before redirecting it to payment gateway. Because every payment gateway including ccavenue needs order id and few parameters related to order. What you can do is , You should stop the mail on order creation.

There is an event

```
sales_order_place_after
```

Override it and stop sending mail when you get response from your payment getway check what is coming success or failure according to that send a proper email.